# Are $\mathbb{N} $ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} $ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}$ similar?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

In other words, my question is: Is there any order preserving bijection between $\mathbb{N} $ $\times$  $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} $ $\times$  $\mathbb{Z}$, with antilexicographic order:

$$ (a,b)<(c,d)⟺(b<d) \lor (b=d \land a<c) $$

(Two sets are *similar* if there exists a bijection between them which keeps the order in sets.)

I know that  $\mathbb{N} $ and  $\mathbb{Z} $ are not similar, but still, I don't know what to do with this task...

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the standard term is "**isomorphic**" (as linear orders), not "similar."

Answer (score 1):

If there where an order-preserving bijection $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ then two consecutive elements would go to two consecutive elements, so $f(a,b)=(c,d)$ implies $f(a+1,b)=(c+1,d)$, this would imply that $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$ are similar.

Comment: Please elaborate, because I don't see how this would imply that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ are similar.

Comment: Another way to see this is taking $f(0,0)=(a,b)$, there are no elements between $(a-1,b)$ and $(a,b)$ so there couldn't be any elements between $f^{-1}(a-1,b)$ and $(0,0)$ but this is clearly imposible, since for any $(c,d)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb Z$ such that $(c,d)<(0,0)$ there are infinitely many elements between $(c,d)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Because what I said above implies that $f(\mathbb N\times\{b\})=f(\mathbb Z\times\{d\})$

Comment: The main difference between this ordered sets is that for any element in $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ there is a previous element and a successor element, whereas in $\mathbb N\times \mathbb Z$ there is not always a previous element. Another interesting question would be the same as the one you asked but with the lexicographic order instead of the antilexicographic.

Comment: Now I get it. I was thinking about the lexicographic order, which is - as you pointed out - much more interesting. In the antilexicographic order the answer is trivial.

Comment: If you take the lexicographic order then (by the same argument) you get that $f(\{a\}\times\mathbb Z)=\{b\}\times\mathbb Z$ so $f$ would induce an order preserving bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @MatíasUres What element of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb Z$ doesn't have a previous element in the antilexicographic order?  Isn't it always the case that $(a, b-1) \lt (a, b)$ so that $(a, b)$ always has a previous element $\forall a \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: that is always the case, but by a "previous" element of $b$ I mean an element $a$ such that $a<b$ and $\{c:a\leq c\leq b\}=\{a,b\}$. Informally I'm saying that there are no elements between $a$ and $b$, by this definition $(0,a)\in\mathbb N\times \mathbb Z$ has no previous element.